# ERROR Unable to find node_modules/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

I am trying to build an ionic project, and when I try to use the command 
 
 `ionic capacitor run android` 
I get an error that says 
`[error] Unable to find node_modules/cordova-plugin-whitelist. Are you sure cordova-plugin-whitelist is installed?
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.` 
and I have checked if cordova-plugin-whitelist is installed and it is 
`Plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" already installed on android.
Adding cordova-plugin-whitelist to package.json` 
How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Did you do an npm i?

Comment: are you using cordova plugins with capacitor project?

Answer (score 5):

This "Unable to find node_modules/X" issue came up for me when running `npx cap sync`, after installing the npm package for a cordova plugin. (context: attempting to use a Cordova plugin in my Capacitor project)

I resolved it by:

1. Closing my code editors (was causing issues for step 2).
2. Running `npm install`.
3. Running `npx cap sync` again.

The `npx cap sync` command then completed successfully.